# How to fix/find 'Bad Request' and 'Denied' authentication errors in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, http-status-code-401, http-status-code-400

I am working on a user registration page in my group project and came across a bad request error when submitting the data. I created a button to get users so I can check the authentication and it gave me a 401. "HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication. (Fetch)GET - http://localhost:49967/Users" When I login, I use the admin login that's in the database and I see a token in my developers options. How do I find this error? I am new to react and programming so if you can lend some advice or docs it would be appreciated.

So to test my api endpoint, I loaded Postman and attempted to GET/POST and everything worked. I am using a react front-end, SQL sever for the database and ASP.Net Core in Visual Studios c#.

For starters here is the const I am using to access the back end

```
const apiHelper = {
  get(url, params){
    return fetch(`${baseUrl}${url}`, {
      headers: this.headers
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
       return Promise.resolve();
     });
  }
```

This is the onclick action

```
handleGetUsers = async() => {
   const response = await apiHelper.get('Users')
   if(response){
     console.log(response)
   }
 }
```

Lastly my URL
http://localhost:49967/

Comment: Can you provide the detailed code. Developer options? You mean the localStorage or sessionStorage right. Check if you are passing correct Headers in fetch.

Comment: Ok i just switched browsers and it gave me the option to locate the line of code causing the error. it gave me this: ```SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" ```   and from what i am reading, this is whats causing the error  ````console.log(error);````

Comment: Headers for fetch ````const defaultHeaders = {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};````

Comment: Where is the token been sent in header.. Based on your backend implementation. Headers should contain something like access-token: 'yrrsdfsf8JPN4n7qHZ9dlpZQsf' for getting authenticated.

Comment: It sends to the authenticate api and check if the credentials match and generates the bearer token

Comment: Refer this example http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/09/11/react-basic-http-authentication-tutorial-example. Hope you get all your answers